# How do I exclude last node

Tags: xpath

I have following html tag structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><div class="MainContentTextContainer">
<br/> To break the stalemate of heavy competition and low growth in the traditional orthopedic implant markets, the major orthopedic companies are turning to biologics. This white paper provides some information on this trend. Information from this White Paper was obtained from Kalorama's full market study on this market 'The World Market for Orthopedic Biomaterials SKU KLI6329663," as well as news media sources. <br/>
<br/>
<p> "We also feature department and global pricing for reports that we be utilized by more than one user at your company."
</p>
<p>
<b>Related Reports:</b>
</p>
<!-- [PID:6921310] -->
<a href="http://www.kaloramainformation.com/Global-Medical-Devices-6921310/" class="StandardLink DkBlueType">The Global Market for Medical Devices, 3rd. Edition</a>
<br/>May 2, 2012 - KLI3873247 - $1,995.00<br/>
<br/>

</div>
```

Above is my html node structure.I want to return MainContentTextContainer node which does not contain nodes after last `<p>` tag which contains 'Related Reports:'.

means i want expected output as:

```
<div class="MainContentTextContainer">
    <br/> To break the stalemate of heavy competition and low growth in the traditional orthopedic implant markets, the major orthopedic companies are turning to biologics. This white paper provides some information on this trend. Information from this White Paper was obtained from Kalorama's full market study on this market 'The World Market for Orthopedic Biomaterials SKU KLI6329663," as well as news media sources. <br/>
    <br/>
    <p> "We also feature department and global pricing for reports that we be utilized by more than one user at your company."
    </p>   
    </div>
```

I have used following xpath:

```
//div[@class='MainContentTextContainer']/*[not(self::p[last()])]
```

but it is not working.
Please guide me with proper xpath.

Thanks.

Comment: XPath is a *query* language for XML documents. As such it cannot modify an XML document -- such as deleting nodes from it. What you want is called *transformation* and it can be trivially accomplished using XSLT. Would you be interested in an XSLT solution?

Answer (score 0):

This XPath expressions returns all the text and element nodes inside the `div` that are followed by a `p`, which means the last `p` and the nodes following it are not included:

```
(//div[@class='MainContentTextContainer']/* | //div[@class='MainContentTextContainer']/text())[following-sibling::p]
```